# How can changing environments make my super-villain super-powered while causing chronic (extreme) pain?

Tags: science-fiction, environment, earth-like, super-powers

I have a super-villain who is from another environment( e.g. aquatic, extra-terrestrial, extra-dimensional ( Bonus points for the least extreme from populous land-locked earth )) They are not a remarkable person in their native environment but also not without skills that will later help them.

However when they leave their native environment for ours they gain super powers. These powers need to make them powerful but not nigh-invincible (like Super-man.) Mixed with strong tactical sense and charisma (which they possess on their own) they become an extremely formidable opponent. The catch? The powers also come with chronic (extreme) pain, which will be a major contributing factor in the villains pathos.

**Constraints:**

1. Effects should be temporary. Recreating the original environment will not be used as a "kryptonite" but it is preferable that all conditions reverse on returning to home environment. Permanent change will be accepted if no temporary alternative remains.
2. The superpower(s) should probably be physical in nature (speed, reflexes, strength, bullet-proof, etc...) but it isn't necessary. As long as they combine well with charisma and tactics to make an exceptional foe.
3. The superpower(s) and the pain should be intrinsically linked. One should not be able to be removed without the other.

**Question:**

Where is he from? What is his super power? What is his condition/ cause of pain?

Comment: this seems to fall into the "do my work for me question", if you change what you are asking to fit the rules on this site then we can help. also how will we know what would be the best answer give, maybe change the vagueness of your question to narrow down the answer. like who will he be fighting, why is he a villain ect. the devil is in the details

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding. Please read [this](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) to get a better understanding on how your question can be modified to fit this site. Also please take the [tour] and visit the [help].

Comment: I'm pretty sure the villain you're inventing already exists, although I can't remember his name, as a Silver Age foe of either Supergirl or Superboy. His powers under a yellow sun are actually stronger than Kryptonians', but because of his pain he can't use them as effectively, which is why the good guys were able to defeat him.

Comment: (Also, while I'd stopped reading those comics by the Dark Age, I wouldn't be surprised if they brought him back, and gave him some super-heroin for the pain, so he's unstoppable except when he goes into withdrawal.)

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding.SE!  We're glad you could join us!  When you have a moment, please [click here](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6388/welcome-to-worldbuilding-se?noredirect=1) to learn more about our culture and take our [tour].  Also, please review our Meta page about [High Concept questions](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4868/how-to-deal-with-please-develop-my-high-concept-questions).

Comment: Maybe your hero is Jesus?

Comment: Please see [sandbox post](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6692/809) and help OP get this reopened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm thinking a normal Earth-like planet, but with a much lower level of oxygen in the atmosphere to what we're familiar with.

The increased supply of O2 would mean that the muscles have an abundant supply of O2 which in theory wouldn't necessarily increase strength, but would shift the line between aerobic activity (activity which burns O2 at or less than the rate that it can be replenished) and anaerobic activity (that which burns O2 faster than it can be replenished by the body).

In other words, you could sprint for a lot longer, jump as high but more often, etc.

The problem? [Oxygen Toxicity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxygen_toxicity). On Earth, this can be fatal in extended periods, but can also be very painful to experience and dangerous to human anatomy like eyes.

Your person from a lower O2 level in the air will have larger lungs as a proportion of their body size to pull in more O2 and that means that their lungs would be in a lot of agony, as would their eyes. Assuming that we are just under the fatally toxic levels for your otherworld species, this guarantees that they are in a lot of pain, but theoretically could function a lot better than average humans.

It also fits the brief insofar as your humanoids could come from a planet of similar food availability, gravity, etc. as Earth, in fact similar in almost every respect, except that their planet has a much lower O2 partial pressure. If we assume that the atmospheric density at sea level is equivalent, O2 may be as low as 10 to 15% and still be able to support this species there, but cause problems in our own atmosphere.